# Does the DataTypeAttribute on a model do validation in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

The default ASP.net MVC 3 Internet Application template includes the following model:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

In the Account/Register action it is asking for an email address, but it seems you can type anything in this field and it will accept it.

Does the DataType(DataType.EmailAddress) actually trigger validation? It seems like it does not. If it doesn't validate the type, then what is its purpose?

Comment: I've the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 12):

So far as I'm aware, the DataType attribute is used for formatting but only when you use `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field)`.

Examples from model fields, cshtml and the resulting HTML:

Model fields:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[Display(Name = "Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
[Display(Name = "Description")]
public string Desc { get; set; }
```

Cshtml:

```
<div class="form-section">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
</div>

<div class="form-section">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Password)
</div>

<div class="form-section">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Desc)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Desc)
</div>
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<div class="form-section">
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input class="text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-section">
    <label for="Password">Password</label>
    <input class="text-box single-line password" id="Password" name="Password" type="password" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-section">
    <label for="Desc">Description</label>
    <textarea class="text-box multi-line" id="Desc" name="Desc"></textarea>
</div>
```

I know it's an old post, but maybe I can shine a light on the situation for others that come this way

EDIT:

There *may* be some validation attached to these but only client side. Do not rely on these attributes for actual validation, this should always be done server side (client side is only for user experience)

Answer (score 4):

There is NO validation associated with the DataType attributes in the current release of MVC3.

New attributes deriving from this attribute are shown in MVC Futures and add this validation process. For example, `EmailAddressAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

DataType attributes are not validation attributes.  They're used for templating. ex. you can use the html 5 email tag for DataType.Email. JakeJ's detailed it.

Answer (score 0):

The default template doesn't add the proper Validate.js scripts to the master page. The data annotations just output HTML that the javascript reads to do the client-side validation.

In your controller action you need to do Model.IsValid to ensure validation server-side.

Comment: The default template adds all that. THat's what I'm trying to say. The default Internet Application adds the client side scripts...it adds the Model.IsValid to the controller action and it STILL doesn't validate.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get that validator to work either and ended up writing my own similar to [one found on the ASP.net site](http://forums.asp.net/t/1639798.aspx/1/10?MVC%203%20DataType%20EmailAddress%20client%20side%20validation%20problems%20). Supposedly an [EmailAddress] annotation is available in MVC3 Future.

Answer (score 0):

DataType attributes are used by the templated views when using editorfor()