# Uses of Datatype.EmailAddress in asp/.net/mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Account Model in which I am using Email Address as Username

```
public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
```

I have designed a custom class to verify email. But I recently noticed that the `DataType.EmailAddress`. I tried to use this Datatype as shown in code above to check if I can validate the Username without my Custom Class but it fails. So my question is how is this DataType useful in **`.NET`**. It seems to be doing nothing on my Registration Form.

**Edit:** It dosent even validate against a regex. For example Username: `SS, ssssss, tttt, etc` all pass off as valid emails.

**Edit: People I have a class to validate email in the code behind. I know hat are the complexities of validating Emails. I am not asking how to validate email. I am just asking about the uses of this datatype.**

Comment: You can make an EditorTemplate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mvc \[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress) no validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453574/mvc-datatypedatatype-emailaddress-no-validation)

Comment: @jumpingcode Please see my edit why this question is different.

Comment: DataType attribute is used for formatting purposes, not for validation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550487/does-the-datatypeattribute-on-a-model-do-validation-in-mvc-3

Comment: @jumpingcode can you please explain how that question explains what this datatype does?

Comment: If you looked at the answers, it would tell you. Instead you just looked at the question, you have to do a bit of the work yourself you know

Comment: @jumpingcode - I did go look at the link and the top answer a) does not address using *DataType[EmailAddress]* and b) is using editors which do not impact what this DataType does (hint:  it only changes the display template).  The only answer that had remotely anything to do with the *EmailAddress* type was deleted and could not be seen by him (or you even?)

Comment: `DataType attributes are used by the templated views when using editorfor()`

Comment: @jumpingcode - "impact what **this** DataType does".  Not trying to start a comment war here, rather politely stating you were a little rough in your presentation as it related to the question being asked.

Comment: @Tommy Point taken and +1 for the answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, you are asking what this data type does not why isn't it validating, correct?  Per the MSDN, DataType attributes are used primarily for formatting and not validation (which you have learned).  What this attribute should do, is when using the `Html.DisplayFor()` helper, render the field as a clickable hyperlink.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.UserName)
```

Renders

```
<a href="mailto:{0}">{0}</a>
```

Additionally, as pointed out by Zhaph in the comments below, using it in the `Html.EditorFor()` will generate an HTML 5 email input, which looks something like this:

```
<input type="email".../>
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype.aspx)

> The following example uses the DataTypeAttribute to customize the
>   display of EmailAddress data field of the customer table in the
>   AdventureWorksLT database. The e-mail addresses are shown as
>   hyperlinks instead of the simple text that ASP.NET Dynamic Data would
>   have inferred from the intrinsic data type.

Comment: It can also be used by the `EditorFor` helper to generate an `<input type="email" [...] />` HTML5 input field.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid - cool, that might be something new in 4.5  (which I am not sure was available back when this question was first posted :) ) - and definitely useful!

Answer (score 13):

`DataType` alone will not trigger any server-side validation. But, since MVC 4 using `DataType.EmailAddress` will make the HTML input use `type="email"`, which in turn makes jQuery Validation perform Regex validation on the client.

.NET 4.5 introduced the `[EmailAddress]` attribute, a subclass of `DataTypeAttribute`. By using `[EmailAddress]` you get both client and server side validation.

Comment: warning: server side validation is quite simple, it checks only if "@" is part of the input string

Comment: from 4.7.2 regex email validation is disabled and you have to enable it look this issue
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0ce2ad75-33f9-4e0c-8766-9422bfb5bdc6/emailaddressattribute-not-working-correctly

Answer (score 4):

you can use the EmailAddress data annotation or the regex to solve this issue. Date type is used to tell the html helper to render the html for the view.

```
[EmailAddress]
[RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Must be a valid Email Address")]
```

Answer (score 2):

`Datatype.Emailaddress` derives from `DataTypeAttribute` and adds client-side e-mail validation you also need to set `<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>` in your corresponding view.

Alternatively you could use the DataAnnotations library by using `EmailAddress` (This performs server side validation)

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public String Email { get; set; }
```

This is the regex to validate Email address

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Email is required")]
[RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z] {2,4}",
public String Email {get; set;}
```

You can also create custom email validation Attribute.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx