# Annotation for checking that an email address is valid in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to validate that an email address entered by the user is a valid email address.  I have tried to use the following data annotation which I read should work:

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [DisplayName("Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

So as you can see I have used the [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)].  This does not seem to work.  Is there any other method that I can use to check that an email address is valid.  I have spent the last 108 hours working on this and I feel that it is about time I move on.

Comment: Define "Valid". Define "does not seem to work".

Comment: Have you seen the [`EmailAddressAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Seems very similar to [Uses of Datatype.EmailAddress in asp/.net/mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19425916/33051)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp validation

```
[RegularExpression("/^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$/", ErrorMessage = "Lorem ipsum bla bla")]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following mark-up it will render an html 5 input type email:

**Markup**

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
```

**Rendered output**

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" 
 data-val-required="The Email Address field is required." 
 id="Email" name="Email" type="email" value="">
```

This will prevent invalid submission for html 5 compliant browsers.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uwzx12w/)**

Answer (score 0):

The System.Net.Mail.MailAddress class can handle this. It will throw a FormatException if the address is in an unrecognized format. See this on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19426816/33051):

`Datatype.Emailaddress` derives from `DataTypeAttribute` and adds client-side e-mail validation you also need to set `<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>` in your corresponding view.

As hutchonoid points out, this will generate an HTML5 `<input type="email" ... />` input field, which will allow the browser to pre-validate for you as well as provide the "Email" keyboard on mobile devices.

For server-side valdiation you could use the `DataAnnotations` library by using `EmailAddressAttribute`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 

[Required]
[EmailAddress]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[DisplayName("Email Address")]
public String Email { get; set; }
```

Alternatively, you could use the `RegularExpressionAttribute` and get both client and server side validation, but without the HTML5 field rendering.