# How to use dataannotation validation in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I need your help, I have wrote this class to hold the data, here in my example I used the *DataAnnotation* for validation, unfortunately I entered in invalid email address but it did not object so I am confused about what is the correct way to use the *DataAnnotations*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace workflow.DataHolders
{
    public class NewCompany
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage="Length Should  Be More Than Three Letters")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Length Should  Be More Than Two Letters")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by valid Email address? can you put an example?

Comment: take a look at this answer, it's well explained http://stackoverflow.com/a/26329350/4773983

Comment: @Ala I edited  it, invalid*

Comment: What to you mean _"it did not object"_? What are you expecting? Do your have client side validation enabled? Have you included `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` helpers in the view. Do you check `ModelState.IsValid` in the POST method?

Answer (score 0):

We have two way to do this

**1st Way**

```
[RegularExpression(@"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
public string email { get; set; }
```

**2nd Way**

```
 [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
 [Email]
 public string email { get; set; }
```