# What is DataType(DataType. *) used for?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have used Data Attributes like `[EmailAddress]` and     `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`
for server side validation  in asp.net core mvc and for mapping in Entity Framework Core, but never `DataType(DataType.Example)` , I tried to search about it but i still don't understand the concept or the purpose of it.

 So what im looking for is an explanation with examples about the practical use of it. You can use the following example as a reference.

```
    public class ProvidingContext
{
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype

Answer (score 4):

The attribute is merely an *annotation* (it tells something about a property, but doesn't do anything by itself), and [documented as such](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype?view=netcore-3.1):

> Represents an enumeration of the data types associated with data fields and parameters.

What MVC does with it, isn't really documented. There [is an official MVC tutorial that explains some of its usage though](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

> The DataType attributes only provide hints for the view engine to format the data (and supplies elements/attributes such as  for URL's and  for email. You can use the RegularExpression attribute to validate the format of the data. The DataType attribute is used to specify a data type that's more specific than the database intrinsic type, they're not validation attributes. In this case we only want to keep track of the date, not the time.
>
> The DataType Enumeration provides for many data types, such as Date, Time, PhoneNumber, Currency, EmailAddress and more. The DataType attribute can also enable the application to automatically provide type-specific features. For example, a mailto: link can be created for DataType.EmailAddress, and a date selector can be provided for DataType.Date in browsers that support HTML5.
>
> The DataType attributes emit HTML 5 data- (pronounced data dash) attributes that HTML 5 browsers can understand. The DataType attributes do not provide any validation.

See also:

- [Does the DataTypeAttribute on a model do validation in MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550487/does-the-datatypeattribute-on-a-model-do-validation-in-mvc-3)
- [EmailAddress or DataType.Email attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994423/emailaddress-or-datatype-email-attribute)

So: Razor uses it for rendering attributes such that browsers can show native validation and selection controls (e.g. date pickers, numeric input, ...).

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to what @codecaster said the `EmailAddress` attribute derives from the `DataTypeAttribute` and adds server-side validation while the `DataType` attribute defines the input type only.

So the `EmailAddress` attribute gives you both functionalities.